# Symfony2 and Doctrine multiple ManyToMany relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a model with three main elements: Questions, Answers and Games. Each of them whould have Tags associated, but those Tags needs to be shared. I mean, the same tags should be used for the three kind of elements: the "Science" tag should be applied to either a Question, an Answer or a Game, or the three of them.

How should I do this? Do I add a ManyToMany field in the Tags entity for each kind of element, or is there any other way to relate them? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose option 1) add ManyToMany relationship on each entities.

```
class Question
{
    // ... 

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     *
     **/
    private $tags;
}

class Answer
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     *
     **/
    private $tags;
}

class Game
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     *
     **/
    private $tags;
}
```

Comment: Well you can have a look at this Doctrine extension https://github.com/FabienPennequin/DoctrineExtensions-Taggable

Comment: With this solution, the Tag entity will have 3 associations and every Tag object will have 2 null association. I think Ikzer is looking for something cleaner.

Comment: Right. In this case, my Tag would have a QuestionID,AnswerID and gameID, and usually two of them will be unnecesarily empty.

Comment: The Taggable extensión looks good, I think i'll use it, thanks!